# Easy way to compare two List<String> and keep only unique values

Tags: c#, list, data-structures

I am trying to Compare two lists and keep on each list only items that are unique to each list. Could you assist?

I know how to do intersection, but I actually need to do the opposite

```
        //Example
        List<String> baseListCopy = new List<String>();
        baseListCopy.Add("Test1");
        baseListCopy.Add("Test2");
        baseListCopy.Add("Test3");
        baseListCopy.Add("Test4");
        baseListCopy.Add("Test5");
        baseListCopy.Add("Test6");
        baseListCopy.Add("Test7");
        baseListCopy.Add("Test8");
        baseListCopy.Add("Test9");

        List<String> resultListCopy = new List<String>();
        resultListCopy.Add("Test1");
        resultListCopy.Add("Test2");
        resultListCopy.Add("Test3");
        resultListCopy.Add("Test40");
        resultListCopy.Add("Test90");

        //returns only items that are present on both lists
        resultListCopy = baseListCopy.Intersect(resultListCopy, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase).ToList();

        //How do I return only items that are unique to that list?
```

Comment: "items that are not appearing on any of the lists" : that's a lot of strings...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get all results that are **not** contained in `resultListCopy`:

```
resultListCopy = baseListCopy.Except(resultListCopy, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
                             .ToList();
```

Answer (score 7):

Your question is unclear.

It sounds like you want all items that appear in exactly one list (XOR):

```
a.Union(b).Except(a.Intersect(b))
```

Answer (score 3):

It's not clear what you mean by "that list" but I think you want [`Except`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.except.aspx):

```
// Just to avoid scrolling :)
var comparer = StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase;
var baseListOnly = baseListCopy.Except(resultListCopy, comparer)
                               .ToList();
```

Note that you can populate lists much more easily using collection initializers:

```
List<String> baseListCopy = new List<String> { 
    "Test1", "Test2", "Test3",
    "Test4", ...
};
```

If you're *actually* after items which are in exactly one list, then another alternative to SLaks' answer would be to use [`HashSet<T>.SymmetricExceptWith`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336848.aspx):

```
var hashSet = new HashSet<string>(baseListCopy,  
                                  StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
// This mutates the set
hashSet.SymmetricExceptWith(resultListCopy);
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you take the intersection and iterate through it, removing each value from the base that is in the intersection. Try:

```
resultListCopy = baseListCopy.Intersect(resultListCopy, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase).ToList();
resultList = new List<String>();
foreach (string s in resultListCopy )
{
    if (!baseListCopy.contains(s))
        resultList.add(s);
}
```

Or with resultListCopy and base List swapped if that's what you meant.

Comment: Hi, actually I did this, but I wanted to do it more elegant with less code. @BrokenGlass actually gave me exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

A slight variant to SLaks' post:

```
var finalListCopy = 
  baseListCopy.Except(resultListCopy).Union(resultListCopy.Except(baseListCopy));
```

Two Excepts joined in a Union... :D